Using GNU Radio how would I create a demodulator/modulator for BPSK?
Using GNU Radio how would I create a demodulate/modulator for BPSK? I want to then phase shift out the re-modulated signal to remove it as much as possible

Hi Max! This is a bit of an overly broad question. You can find the answer to this actually as an advanced chapter in the official GNU Radio tutorials, at https://tutorials.gnuradio.org

Your math here by the way is wrong: you cannot add a phase shift. That's a multiplicative operation. In case you need some accustoming with the idea of complex baseband, https://pysdr.org has an SDR-focused introduction.

its a 180 degree phase shift. so it would be like adding back the inverse of the signal would it not?

no, it would not. As said, phase shifting is a multiplicative operation! For 180°, the multiplication would be with a constant -1. Yep, definitely fresh up your complex baseband and what phase is to these complex numbers :)

Making a BPSK to make a BPSK tx/rx using SDR devices, you should first use a symbol synchronization block to obtain the optimal sampling point after matched filtering. In addition, you will face a CFO effect at the receiver since BPSK is a coherent modulation. Secondly, the effect of the CFO must be eliminated using a blind or decision-based algorithm.
If you want to add a phase shift to a BPSK signal directly, you cannot see this effect in the RX signal if you use SDR devices and blind CFO algorithms. This is because

The wireless channel itself is a source of random phase.
The CFO always creates an initial phase.
Most CFO compensation algorithms discard the effect of the initial phase.

To avoid the aforementioned factors, RX/TX devices must be synchronized over the same clock. (ie, If you use the same device for both RX and TX, their clocks will be inherently in-sync.) If so, you don't need to CFO compensation algorithm, but you will still need the symbol synchronization algorithm which is available for BPSK in GnuRadio thankfully. Lastly, if you are working with over-the-air signals, before the symbol synchronization algorithm, I recommend you place an AGC block to provide a constant gain signal to the synchronization block.
